# vtkRenderWindowInteractor stalling program

Tags: python, multithreading, listener, render, vtk

I've been working on a prototype application in Python for stereoscopic imaging of a 3D model using VTK, but I'm running into some issues on the interface end of things. The goal of the code below at the moment is to zoom in on both renderWindows when the middlemouse is pressed. However, upon calling the `vtkRenderWindowInteractor.Start()` function, my `vtkRenderWindowInteractor`s are effectively stalling out the entire program as if they were being run in the same thread. Even more curious is that keyboard interrupts are not being thrown when I use CTRL-C (I'm working in UNIX shell) until I close the render windows manually using the 'x' button. If I just close the window manually without hitting CTRL-C, the program picks up directly after the `Start()` call (e.g. in the code below, the infinite while loop). I've provided a sequence of screen captures at the end of this post to visualize exactly what is happening in the case that my explanation is confusing.

I've tried multiple workarounds to remedy this but none so far have worked. Threading the renders into isolated threads made no difference even when I tried using ncurses for input, while forking them to a new process resulted in some OS issues that I'd rather not deal with. The most current interactor styles method (shown below) where I just use built-in VTK listeners works to a degree, allowing me to detect inputs when the windows are in focus and the interactors are active, but because of the lack of association between the camera and the `MyInteractorStyle` class, I can't really access the cameras without the inclusion a loop after the `Start()` call, which leads me right back to where I started.

Any thoughts? Am I just misunderstanding how VTK's render tools are supposed to be used?

```
from vtk import*
import os.path
#import thread
#import time
#import threading 
#import curses

class MyInteractorStyle(vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera):

        pos1 = [0, 0, 200]
        foc1 = [0, 0, 0]
        pos2 = [40, 0, 200]
        foc2 = [0, 0, 0]

        def __init__(self,parent=None):
                self.AddObserver("MiddleButtonPressEvent", self.middleButtonPressEvent)
                self.AddObserver("MiddleButtonReleaseEvent", self.middleButtonReleaseEvent)
        def middleButtonPressEvent(self,obj,event):
                print "Middle button pressed"
                self.pos1[2] += 10
                self.pos2[2] += 30
                self.OnMiddleButtonDown()
                return
        def middleButtonReleaseEvent(self,obj,event):
                print "Middle button released"
                self.OnMiddleButtonUp()
                return
def main():


        # create two cameras
        camera1 = vtkCamera()
        camera1.SetPosition(0,0,200)
        camera1.SetFocalPoint(0,0,0)

        camera2 = vtkCamera()
        camera2.SetPosition(40,0,200)
        camera2.SetFocalPoint(0,0,0)


        # create a rendering window and renderer
        ren1 = vtkRenderer()
        ren1.SetActiveCamera(camera1)

        ren2 = vtkRenderer()
        ren2.SetActiveCamera(camera2)

        # create source
        reader = vtkPolyDataReader()
        path = "/home/compilezone/Documents/3DSlicer/SlicerScenes/LegoModel-6_25/Model_5_blood.vtk"
        reader.SetFileName(path)
        print(path)
        reader.Update()

        # create render window

        renWin1 = vtkRenderWindow()
        renWin1.AddRenderer(ren1)

        renWin2 = vtkRenderWindow()
        renWin2.AddRenderer(ren2)

        # create a render window interactor

        inputHandler = MyInteractorStyle()

        iren1 = vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
        iren1.SetRenderWindow(renWin1)
        iren1.SetInteractorStyle(inputHandler)

        iren2 = vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
        iren2.SetRenderWindow(renWin2)
        iren2.SetInteractorStyle(inputHandler)

        # mapper
        mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper()
        mapper.SetInput(reader.GetOutput())

        # actor
        actor = vtkActor()
        actor.SetMapper(mapper)

        # assign actor to the renderer
        ren1.AddActor(actor)
        ren2.AddActor(actor)

        # enable user interface interactor
        iren1.Initialize()
        iren2.Initialize()
        renWin1.Render()
        renWin2.Render()
        iren1.Start()
        iren2.Start()
        print "Test"
        while 1:
                pos1 = iren1.GetInteractorStyle().pos1
                foc1 = iren1.GetInteractorStyle().foc1
                pos2 = iren2.GetInteractorStyle().pos2
                foc2 = iren2.GetInteractorStyle().foc2
                print     

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Program running
[image]
KeyboardInterrupt (CTRL-C hit and echoed in terminal but nothing happens)
[image]
Render windows manually closed, KeyboardInterrupt thrown
[image]

Comment: Apparently the `Start()` method is supposed to only return on manual close of the window according to documentation, but that actually raises more questions than it answers. How could both `iren1`'s and `iren2`'s `Start()` methods be called if `iren1`'s `Start()` didn't return until closing the window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `Start()` on a RenderWindowInteractor starts the event loop necessary to execute render events, much as the event loop in a GUI. So what you're trying to do, starting two event loops, doesn't really make sense.

A conceptual workaround would be to not call `Start` on the RenderWindowInteractors but to write a small GUI with multiple toolkit-specific RenderWindowInteractors and use that GUI's event loop.

As an example, here's how this is done with GUI toolkit-specific code in tvtk's wxVtkRenderWindowInteractor class, which doesn't call start on the RenderWindowInteractor but instead uses the GUI's event loop to manage events:

```
def wxVTKRenderWindowInteractorConeExample():
 """Like it says, just a simple example
 """
 # every wx app needs an app
 app = wx.PySimpleApp()

 # create the top-level frame, sizer and wxVTKRWI
 frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "wxVTKRenderWindowInteractor", size=(400,400))
 widget = wxVTKRenderWindowInteractor(frame, -1)
 sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
 sizer.Add(widget, 1, wx.EXPAND)
 frame.SetSizer(sizer)
 frame.Layout()

 # It would be more correct (API-wise) to call widget.Initialize() and
 # widget.Start() here, but Initialize() calls RenderWindow.Render().
 # That Render() call will get through before we can setup the
 # RenderWindow() to render via the wxWidgets-created context; this
 # causes flashing on some platforms and downright breaks things on
 # other platforms.  Instead, we call widget.Enable().  This means
 # that the RWI::Initialized ivar is not set, but in THIS SPECIFIC CASE,
 # that doesn't matter.
 widget.Enable(1)

 widget.AddObserver("ExitEvent", lambda o,e,f=frame: f.Close())

 ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
 widget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(ren)

 cone = vtk.vtkConeSource()
 cone.SetResolution(8)

 coneMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
 coneMapper.SetInput(cone.GetOutput())

 coneActor = vtk.vtkActor()
 coneActor.SetMapper(coneMapper)

 ren.AddActor(coneActor)

 # show the window
 frame.Show()

 app.MainLoop()
```

(Note that this code is not altered and has some clear differences with what you are trying to do.)

Also, the reason that ctrl+C doesn't work is because the VTK event loop doesn't do anything with this event. Some GUIs do respect this event, including wxpython. But if you aren't using a GUI that respects this event (for example, Qt) you can manually tell the python interpreter to intercept this event and crash instead of forwarding the event to the GUI event loop:

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
```

Comment: Good to know why CTRL-C wasn't working. 

I would prefer not to use another GUI as I am sure it can be done in VTK alone. Is there any way for me to write an event listener that manipulates the camera on its own, similar to, say, the `leftButtonPressEvent()` VTK provides? I have looked for the source to this listener but all I've found are headers, so I'm at a loss for examples.

I upvoted you because the information you provided was good, but the solution you provided doesn't fit the scope of my project. Is there any chance you could provide a purely VTK solution?

Comment: What is the meaning of "an event listener that manipulates the camera on its own"?  That seems inconsistent with the idea of an event listener, which listens for *events.* I don't know what you even mean by that. Do you mean to create an event listener that listens to a periodic event which repeats at regular intervals? I suspect you could do that but it would be difficult and I don't see how that would help.

Comment: Apologies, I'll clarify. In the provided `vtkInteractorStyles` classes in VTK, there are event handlers such as `middleButtonPressEvent()`, `leftButtonPressEvent()`, etc. I am trying to figure out how to use these handlers (or write my own) to allow me to manipulate the camera through my own handlers instead of through the included ones. The end goal is to be able to manipulate the camera with gyroscope data instead of with the mouse. Obviously this means a GUI is unnecessary, so I need a way of changing camera orientation , position, etc. without using the provided `vtkInteractorStyles`

Comment: Take a look at 'vtkCustomInteractorStyle'. Also look at how GUIs override the default interactor styles by intercepting GUI events.

Comment: I just read my original question again and you absolutely answered it. I should have made a new question to ask about my `vtkInteractorStyles` issue, but thank for the responses nonetheless. I'll check that out.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who happens to stumble along this with the same problem of being unable to manipulate the camera from the `vtkInteractorStyle` classes, check out the `Dolly()`, `Pan()`, `Spin()`, `Rotate()`, `Zoom()`, and `UniformScale()`. All of these should let you access the camera from your whichever child class of `vtkInteractorStyle` you're using. Good luck!

EDIT: Even better, just attach your camera to your class that inherits from `vtkInteractorStyle` as a property, e.g.:

`style = MyInteractorStyleClass()
style.camera = myCam`

This way you can access it from anywhere within your custom class! Pretty basic, but it flew right past me.